# Limit in dynamic 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

The program creates a 2D array with `malloc` and `func` fills it. `fprintf` writes in a file. That's all folks.

But I am getting unexpected program exit form the program if I use big integers for `height` and `width`.

(30,60): OK

(60,80): not OK

(60,65): OK

(17,41): OK

(200,200): not OK

Does anybody have a clue?

```
int main() {

    unsigned char **buf = (unsigned char **)malloc(height * sizeof(unsigned char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        buf[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * sizeof(unsigned char));

    func(buf);

    FILE * f = fopen("foo.txt", "w+");
    for(int i= 0;i<height;++i)
        fprintf(f, "%s%c", buf[i], '\n');
    fclose(f);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        free(buf[i]);
    free(buf);
}        

void func(unsigned char** buf) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            buf[i][j] = 48 + (i/10)%10;
        buf[i][width] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to **allocate space for** `'\0'`

Comment: You're mixing `height` and `image_height` as well as `width` and `image_width` – while there isn't a definition visible for any of them. Are you sure they are *all* correctly initialised?

Comment: Fyi, [mcve] means we can compile what you posted; we can't for several reasons, not  the least of which is missing variables, missing initial values, missing `#include` stack, missing prototype for `func` before first-use. At best you get guesses, and while it may help you out, it makes for lousy answers to help future readers. Please keep this in mind. Also fyi, [don't cast `malloc` in C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I translated it wrong, sorry. I will update the question. But @pmg nailed it.

Comment: The solution to that is *don't translate*. Reduce to minimal while still producing your issue, then copy/paste. If you can reproduce with what is posted (and *only* what is posted) then odds are we can too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **allocate space for** `'\0'`

> ```
> buf[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(image_width * sizeof(unsigned char));
>
> buf[i][width] = '\0';
> ```

`buf[i][width]` does not exist

Try

```
buf[i] = malloc(image_width + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line writes outside the array.

```
buf[i][width] = '\0';
```

You need to allocate one more character.

```
buf[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc((width + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

And make sure to use `height` and `width` everywhere.